# Why is strtotime one week off?

Tags: php, strtotime

```
strtotime("third Saturday October 2011")
```

Should be 10/15/2011. However, it's coming up at 10/22/2011. I assume this is because October 2011 starts on a Saturday and PHP is looking at the first full week. Since 10/1/2011 is a Saturday not a full week it ignores it.

Some research suggested putting "of" between the day of the week and the month should fix it but that doesn't work.

Any suggestions on why this is happening and what I can do to correct it?

Comment: Could it be because of the timezone that's set in php.ini? Food for you thoughts =D

Comment: I would avoid using `strtotime` like this.  It's possible, and done often, but strtotime (and the legacy date functions) are rather... buggy...  The code behind them is quite ...interesting...  Use the `DateTime` class instead...

Comment: are you referring to: http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php

Comment: `strtotime` has been pretty handy every time I've used it. A bug in a end-of-lifed variant of PHP is hardly a reason to not use the function...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a documented flaw in PHP <5.2.7 (see [strtotime](http://php.net/strtotime)):

> In PHP 5 prior to 5.2.7, requesting a given occurrence of a given
>   weekday in a month where that weekday was the first day of the month
>   would incorrectly add one week to the returned timestamp. This has
>   been corrected in 5.2.7 and later versions.

You'll need to upgrade PHP, or use a work around like Jonathan Kuhn suggests.

Comment: my php version is greater than 5.2.7. I'm running 5.2.10 http://php.net/releases/index.php

Comment: Reviewed what you posted more in depth. Asked the new IT guy for an update. He said he would do it this weekend. (digging the new IT guy so far.)

Answer (score 1):

I was getting the same results as you on php 5.2.6. This works for me although not ideal.

```
echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('Saturday October 2011 +2 weeks'));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php echo date('Y-m-d', strtotime('third Saturday of October 2011')); ?>
```

Works fine for me. Output is `2011-10-15`.

Comment: it errors for me everytime. I'm running PHP 5.2.10 maybe we are using different versions.

Comment: @dcp: 5.2.x is end-of-life (and the newest 5.2 is 5.2.16).  Upgrade to at least 5.2.16, but preferably 5.3.7.

Comment: I wish I could. I have no control over my servers and IT is not likely to update it for me.

Comment: IT will if you point out to higher-ups that running end-of-life PHP is a major security risk.